# Safari Web Extension (iOS) - New Tab and Home Page

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, safari-extension, safari-web-extension

How do I set my own New Tab for Safari web Extension(iOS)? For now, I'd like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) to be the new tab page. Once I learn to do this, I'd like to have my own custom page as the new tab page.

Also, will this take care of the home page settings as well?

I am a swift developer and I am really struggling with how heavily JavaScript dependent the Web Extensions are but I am learning.